# How does this list comprehension work?

Tags: python, syntax, list-comprehension

```
list1 = ['Hello', 10, None]
list2 = [g.lower() for g in list1 if isinstance(g, str)]
list3 = [g.lower() if isinstance(g,str) else g for g in list1]
list4 = [isinstance(g, str) and g.lower() or g for g in list1]
```

If I want to convert the string in `list` to lowercase, I can use the method in `list2` and the output will be `['hello']`.

In addition to this conversion, if I want to keep integers (which is `10` in this case) and `None`, the methods in both `list3` and `list4` will work and the output will be `['hello', 10, None]`.

My question is that I can't understand how the method in `list4` works.

Comment: Do not use `list` as a name. `list`  is a builtin function and you'd better leave it alone.

Comment: @gboffi So are list, str, dict, tuple, etc all built-in functions?

Comment: Please post the actual code you are using. As it stands, line 2 should give you an error

Comment: you refer to list2 when you create it. I tried it on my machine, it gives an error. You probably need to replace list2 with list in the 2nd line.

Comment: Also, in my python (2.7.3) list2 to list4 are all['hello']. Are you sure your code is correct?

Comment: I've edited the question to reflect the commenter issues. To OP, yes `list`, `str` etc (you list a number of object constructors) are all built ins.

Comment: @YairDaon I'm sure it works as I said after changing the `list2` to `list`, which I already did in my edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To start, writing code like this:

```
condition and value1 or value2
```

was how people implemented a ternary conditional operator in Python before the:

```
value1 if condition else value2
```

[conditional expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions) was introduced in version 2.5 because of [PEP 0308](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0308).  Using the old method is now deprecated in favor of the slightly more efficient and far more readable newer method.

---

The old method works because of how `and` and `or` operate in Python.  Instead of returning boolean results like in most other languages, these operators return values.

Doing `a and b` returns `a` if `a` evaluates to `False`; otherwise, it returns `b`:

```
>>> 0 and 1
0
>>> 1 and 0
0
>>> 1 and 2
2
>>>
```

Doing `a or b` returns `a` if `a` evaluates to `True`; otherwise, it returns `b`:

```
>>> 1 or 0
1
>>> 0 or 1
1
>>> 1 or 2
1
>>>
```

Also, in case you do not know, `0` evaluates to `False` while every other number evaluates to `True`.

---

Coming to your code, this:

```
isinstance(g, str) and g.lower() or g
```

is actually interpreted by Python like:

```
(isinstance(g, str) and g.lower()) or g
```

Now if `isinstance(g, str)` returns `False` (`g` is not a string):

```
(False and g.lower()) or g
```

`False` is returned by `and`:

```
False or g
```

and then `or` returns `g`.  Thus, we avoided calling `.lower()` on a non-string type.

If however `isinstance(g, str)` returns `True` (`g` is a string):

```
(True and g.lower()) or g
```

`and` returns `g.lower()`:

```
g.lower() or g
```

and then `or` returns `g.lower()`, which is fine because `g` is a string.

---

Summed up, these two expressions:

```
g.lower() if isinstance(g,str) else g

isinstance(g, str) and g.lower() or g
```

are functionally equivalent.  **But please use the first!!**  The other is terrible for readability.

Answer (score 1):

Quoting [**the doc**](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations):

> The expression `x and y` first evaluates `x`; if `x` is false, its
>   value is returned; otherwise, `y` is evaluated and the resulting value
>   is returned.
>
> The expression `x or y` first evaluates `x`; if `x` is true, its value is
>   returned; otherwise, `y` is evaluated and the resulting value is
>   returned.

Because of precedence rules, `isinstance(g, str) and g.lower() or g` is actually evaluated as 
`(isinstance(g, str) and g.lower()) or g` (multiplication is of higher precedence than addition).

That basically means the following:

- if `isinstance(g, str)` is true, result of `g.lower()` will be taken
- otherwise `g` will be taken

As you see, it's the same thing that you have in `list3` operation.